# zc.buildout requirements error when 1.7.0 is installed globally

Tags: python, homebrew, buildout

I'm trying to work around the distribute/setuptools re-merge by updating my buildout-based project to use the latest bootstrap.py script. When I run it from a clean checkout of a project I get the following error because I have zc.buildout 1.7.0 installed globally. I thought the purpose of `bootstrap.py` was to install the required buildout, etc?

What am I missing here?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
$ python bootstrap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 159, in <module>
    ws.require(requirement)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 580, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (zc.buildout 1.7.0 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc.buildout-1.7.0-py2.7.egg), Requirement.parse('zc.buildout==2.2.1'))
```

Here is some relevant parts of my buildout.cfg if it matters

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
include-site-packages = false
show-picked-versions = true
parts =
    python
    gae_sdk
    gae_tools
    app_lib
    nosetests

[versions]
zc.buildout=1.7.1
zc.recipe.egg=1.3.2
setuptools=1.3.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to tell bootstrap what version to pick, explicitly:

```
python bootstrap.py -v 1.7.1
```

to match the version named in your `buildout.cfg`. Bootstrap does not look in `buildout.cfg` to honour version pins; you'd have to re-implement a large chunk of buildout itself to be able to parse the full configuration format (including includes).

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here since I am by no means a python or buildout expert but according to the docs I am lead to believe that `bootstrap.py` should install the proper version of `zc.buildout`. Is there a way to make bootstrap.py upgrade me to a 2.x version? I know I can use `easy_install -U zc.buildout` but I would like to make it as simple as possible for our other teammates.

Comment: @Trii: The easiest way is for you to use a virtualenv and not use a global Python (at least not with Buildout installed globally), really.

Comment: @Trii: This only goes wrong because you have a global buildout installed that setuptools finds; the error message is given because the newest version is found online (on PyPI) plus the local version is older, forcing you to choose between one or the other.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that `bootstrap.py` would install the proper `buildout` into `./bin/buildout` regardless of which `zc.buildout` it found globally. I guess this assumption was wrong.

Comment: @Trii: I don't use buildout as a global install, but I *think* you'd use a globally installed buildout command *instead* of using bootstrap, which is meant to install `bin/buildout` only if you don't have your own `buildout` command.

Comment: I did install it globally when I was brand new at python and didn't know any better. Unfortunately that bad decision was propagated throughout the entire team of python newbies.